# PHPMailer SMTP connect() failed Please Login Browser

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to try send mail using gmail. Unfortunately getting an error which is attached. Tried everything to solve it anyone got any ideas on what could be wrong? I have allowed less secure applications.

```
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f29sm10891032pff.169 - gsmtp
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO curtisboylan.com
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.64.65.142]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250-SMTPUTF8
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO curtisboylan.com2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.64.65.142]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvH534-5.7.14 Po6hfzTwq4hCMvLl_DdV9aGq22R-Ak0Vu_nq3jSd95TekrsnufIKHEH5N5XE4VDyIGA9lJ534-5.7.14 zc-jKgF2YAlfTXogT_7AeKcQBnpv8_5A7P8ZpDq6OXTmtlZA3qIYH1Kp8KgrbTrrOwXwRz534-5.7.14 Qj4-AoQL0mbHuJqW7Bo4wulTCBHBjOyTkMaImncgl9sBb7Iz4_z4fo_MgPJXiMAbmG6nyo534-5.7.14 ERw4U9RM70uqOejxuU9GETtaS36S0> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f29sm10891032pff.169 - gsmtp
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvH534-5.7.14 Po6hfzTwq4hCMvLl_DdV9aGq22R-Ak0Vu_nq3jSd95TekrsnufIKHEH5N5XE4VDyIGA9lJ534-5.7.14 zc-jKgF2YAlfTXogT_7AeKcQBnpv8_5A7P8ZpDq6OXTmtlZA3qIYH1Kp8KgrbTrrOwXwRz534-5.7.14 Qj4-AoQL0mbHuJqW7Bo4wulTCBHBjOyTkMaImncgl9sBb7Iz4_z4fo_MgPJXiMAbmG6nyo534-5.7.14 ERw4U9RM70uqOejxuU9GETtaS36S0> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f29sm10891032pff.169 - gsmtp SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2018-04-30 12:17:15 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-04-30 12:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection f29sm10891032pff.169 - gsmtp SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Code:

```
 <?php 


    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    require 'phpmail/vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    // Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('curtis.boylan@gmail.com', 'First Last');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('curtis.boylan@gmail.com', 'Shehan');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'Test Mail';

    $mail->Body = 'This is Test Mail';


    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Did you try a different email address?

Comment: You might consider this a long shot, but you could always try doing what the error message says and log in via your browser. Gmail treats new login mechanisms as suspicious, so it asks that as an extra confirmation step. There is nothing you can do about it from your code - you must fix it in gmail.

Comment: @Riz-waan Yeah it works

Comment: @Synchro yeah tried that still didn't work, just used another gmail no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Try the display captcha reset as described in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some gmail addressees have different levels of security. You can go into my account and allow access from less secure apps. If other gmail accounts work than there is nothing wrong with the code. This issue is usually present in managed gmail accounts.